# How to permit banner ads but block everything else

Tags: javascript, blocking, adblock, noscript, ghostery

I want to permit banner ads on news pages. Yet retain a strict block on all other scripts.

I usually browse with NoScript and Ghostery on full block. My machine has modest processing power and memory. I often need many browser tabs open at once. NoScript and Ghostery allow me to stop greedy websites consuming all my resources. I relex my script permissions when a website needs it. But otherwise block to retain control.

This seems usually to block all ads. I don't want this. I don't want to deny cash-strapped writers and publishers their income.

Yet when I relax the script blockers, they merely allow scripts.

Ideally, I would allow banner ads universally, but continue to stop all scripts.

Comment: Better, and I voted to reopen.  Just a suggestion:  All of the background info makes this a long read and may discourage some people from getting into the question.  It might get a better response if you strip out the philosophy and other parts that are more commentary than critical technical information.  You could probably get this down to a few paragraphs of very focused content, which would attract more readers.

Comment: Thank you, fixer1234 for your suggestions. My question is indeed improved after cutting the waffle.